# hadoop -version giving me wrong result why? Hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I executed below command: **`hadoop -version`** on hadoop version **1.2.1**

```
vishrant@ubuntu:~$ hadoop -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

I was expecting hadoop version but I got the version of JDK installed on my system. I know that correct command is `hadoop version` *[without hyphen]* but instead of getting error I got the version of JDK why?

Comment: For me running 2.6.0 i get `Error: No command named -version was found. Perhaps you meant hadoop version`. What do you get if you just type `hadoop` ?

Comment: I am using hadoop 1.2.1 and there I am getting this result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `hadoop` script for `1.2.x` has much less checking than more recent versions, at this point (2016) its about 3 years old. You can see the source for it [here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-1.2/bin/hadoop).

In the `1.2.x` script if you type `hadoop -version` the script will hit the final `else` statement where it works out what class to run and sets `$CLASS` to `$COMMAND` (line 338) instead of a class.

You can see what it will run on line 434:

`exec "$JAVA" -Dproc_$COMMAND $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS -classpath "$CLASSPATH" $CLASS "$@"`

So if you type `hadoop version` it will run (removed classpath stuff to keep it short):

`java -Dproc_version -Xmx1000m -classpath <LIBS> org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo`

If you type `hadoop -version` you get:

`java -Dproc_-version -Xmx1000m -classpath <LIBS> -version`

So because the default behavior is to set `$CLASS` to `$COMMAND` you basically end up with it running:

`java -version`

Which is what you're getting.